# How to extract specific letters in string with java

Tags: java

I have some expression in a Java string and a would get the letter, which was on the left side and on the right side of a specific sign.

Here are two examples:

```
X-Y
X-V-Y
```

Now, I need to extract in the first example the letter X and Y in a separate string. And in the second example, I need to extract the letters X, V and Y in a separate string.

How can i implemented this requirement in Java?

Comment: check out StringTokenizer

Comment: So far, you have posted 47 questions, most of this have 1 or more answers. You are free to accept none, if you want. But I think you should accept some of them and finally get the scholar badge :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
String input    = "X-V-Y";
String[] output = input.split("-");  // array with: "X", "V", "Y"
```

Answer (score 1):

use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method with `"-"` token

```
String input = "X-Y-V"
String[] output = input.split("-");
```

now in the output array there will be 3 elements X,Y,V

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] results = string.split("-");
```

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
String input ="X-V-Y";
String[] arr=input.split("-");
```

**output**

```
arr[0]-->X
arr[1]-->V
arr[2]-->Y
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting in on this too!

```
String[] terms = str.split("\\W"); // split on non-word chars
```

Answer (score 1):

you can extract and handle a string by using the following code:

```
String input = "x-v-y";
String[] extractedInput = intput.split("-");
for (int i = 0; i < extractedInput.length - 1; i++) {
    System.out.print(exctractedInput[i]);
}
```

> Output: xvy

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method :

```
public String[] splitWordWithHyphen(String input) {
    return input.split("-");
}
```